# Is there a scale at which different wavelengths of light travel at different speeds?

Tags: speed-of-light, universe, space-expansion, refraction, diffraction

Say you have two resonating plates which are parallel to each other with a gap shorter than a wavelength one is oscillating at with an electric field - wouldn't this act as a plate capacitor without intermediary photons?

Now would that mean you would have a period of time both for the transit between the two points and for the emission/absorption of the photons whereas the static field would only have the speed of light linking the two?

If this is correct, then in a diffuse environment (lots of stuff in space) would longer wavelengths travel faster?  (i.e. they pass through things whereas the shorter wavelengths are constantly absorbed/reemitted?

Wouldn't this make the universe look like it is expanding because the further out you look the more red-shifted everything gets?

Why does space need to expand instead of light propagating differently?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your parallel plate example, but it otherwise sounds like you're describing the variation of refractive index versus wavelength. So yes! Different colors of light do travel different speeds through non-vacuum media.

Perhaps you are tripped up by the idea that the particles with which light interacts could be larger than the wavelength, and so refractive index is not a good way to describe the collective medium's properties? You would be right again. But it is true that if you vary the wavelength scale, the particles could appear to be in different regimes ($\ll\!\lambda$, ~$\lambda$, $\gg\!\lambda$), and thus the light propagation properties could be vastly different.

I'm no astrophysicist, but it's clear that cosmic red shifts could not be explained by propagation delays due to dispersion. The thing is, when you measure the spectra of stars, you can look for the specific spectral lines corresponding to emission from atoms that we know well. Those emission lines are very well-defined by quantum mechanics, so any red shift must be due to a change in how we *measure* the light, rather than simply how the light gets to us (unless the light travels through a nonlinear medium, which is far-fetched).  It turns out that this shift is due to our measurement being in a different reference frame from the emission (i.e. there is a Doppler shift).